# Is there a way to 'Show My Team's Records' filtered by creator?

Tags: reporting, dashboard

I have two dashboards as per the role hierarchy. The subordinate's reports are filtered by 'Created By' field and the value is taken Relative. So whoever is watching the report will see his/her created records (Not owned records).

This is the filter to achieve that.
[image]

But for the dashboard of manager we have the same requirement of showing created records of his/her subordinates. Now the SF built in filter that shows My Team's Records filters the records as per the owner and not the creator. How can this be achieved?

[image]